# how to search in unixtime range in NEST?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I've tested a simple request in Kibana and want to convert it to code using NEST.

```
{
"sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
            "match" : {
            "color" : {
              "query": "red"
            }
          }
        },
       {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1512036771843,
              "lte": 1512051171843,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have any timestamp fields in my data, so I want to use @timestamp variable. For some reason Kibana is using unixtime for search, so I've just copied that from main Kibana window search.

Now I am trying to reproduce the same request with NEST, and can get only

```
{
   "sort":[
      {
         "@timestamp":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "color":{
                     "query":"red"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":[
            {
               "range":{
                  "@timestamp":{
                     "gte":1512042533.022923,
                     "lt":1512056933.022923
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Which is an invalid query for Elastic. Here is my code:

```
var searchResponse = _client.Search<Logs>(s => s
             .Query(q => q.Bool(b=>b.Must(mu=>mu.Match(m =>m.Field(f => f.Color).Query("Red")))
             .Filter(fi => fi.Range(r => r.Field("@timestamp").GreaterThanOrEquals(rangeTime).LessThan(currentTime)))))  
             .Sort(p => p.Descending("@timestamp")));
```

Also, how can I save @timestamp value from Elastic response if this value is not the part of my object model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I can get you on the right track.

> I don't have any timestamp fields in my data, so I want to use @timestamp variable.

I don't understand what you mean here. Does the data in Elasticsearch contain a `date` field named `"@timestamp"`? If so, then it can be queried.

It doesn't have to necessarily map to a property on your C# POCO that represents the `_source` of a document, but it may help to do so if you'd like to work with the response values from your .NET application. Mapping can be done in a few different ways but perhaps the easiest is to use attributes here

```
public class Logs
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [Date(Name = "@timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

To then perform a range query on a `date` field, use the `DateRange` query in NEST

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Logs>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(mu => mu
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Color)
                    .Query("Red")
                )
            )
            .Filter(fi => fi
                .DateRange(r => r
                    .Field("@timestamp")
                    .GreaterThanOrEquals("1512036771843")
                    .LessThan("1512051171843")
                    .Format("epoch_millis")
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Sort(p => p
        .Descending("@timestamp")
    )
);
```

The DateRange query can take [`DateMath` expressions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-math-expressions.html) which have implicit conversions from string. There is no conversion from a numeric value exposed in NEST but using strings for the `epoch_millis` values should work. Values can be expressed in any [valid date format for Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html), just need to specify the `Format()` value so Elasticsearch knows how to parse it.

With `"@timestamp"` field mapped as above, we can use lambda expressions for the timestamp field, and with [operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#_operator_overloading) the query can be written more succinctly

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Logs>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Color)
            .Query("Red")
        ) && +q
        .DateRange(r => r
            .Field(f => f.Timestamp)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals("1512036771843")
            .LessThan("1512051171843")
            .Format("epoch_millis")
        )
    )
    .Sort(p => p
        .Descending(f => f.Timestamp)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  After I realized NEST is using Newtonsoft.JSON I found the solution with the [Date(Name = "@timestamp")]  by myself.  And after that, I just took top 10 records (default elasticsearch value I guess) sorted by descending which I guess is not very efficient, because I didn't dare to put "epoch_millis" into Format method. Also, method overlapping is a bit of complicated concept, so thank you for the example.